# GET COUNTERS with Intel trace Collector&Analyzer and PAPI

Tags: intel, papi

Hy everyone,
I'm trying to get counters using Intel Trace Collector and PAPI, but the stf trace file (opened with Intel Analyzer) does not provide counters.

By following the Collector guide, I edited the conf file adding counters I want to collect:

- COUNTER "PAPI_FP_OPS" ON
- COUNTER "PAPI_BR_CN" ON
- COUNTER "PAPI_TOT_INS" ON

and I set up the VT_CONFIG environment variable to point to this file.

The compilation line is:

**mpiifort -r8 -O3 -xHost -fp-model source -traceback file.F90 -L$VT_SLIB_DIR -L. -lVT -L$PAPI_ROOT/lib64 -lpapi $VT_ADD_LIBS -o file.exe**

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance.